# Cannot create a partition because of out-of-space message

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I have 69GB of un-allocated space on my hard-drive. When I try to create a partition in it, I get the error message below telling me that there is not enough space to create it. Why am I getting this message and how can I create the partition?

[image: Screenshot of Disk Management error message]

Comment: Its bad form to post the same message to other SE boards. Additionally, cross referencing it and not putting the error message here will most likely off-put a lot of people and you'll not get your answer.  Suggest you CLOSE your msg on stackoverflow and include the error message HERE.

Comment: The error message is clearly.  You are trying to create parition larger then the amount you have free.  Try a smaller % of what is free.  DO NOT partition the rest of your hdd into a single parition you leave nothing for the operating system to use for temp files.

Comment: "There is not enough space available on the disk to complete this operation"

Comment: @Ramhound - No there are other partitions. windows already install in one partition. there is 69 GB space that i can not use. how can i get back it ?

Comment: Why don't you just extend the C parition?  Do a search on how to extend your C partition.  I have no idea HOW you got that error image since your question doesn't contain an actual question.

Comment: @Ramhound, the free space is within an Extended partition.  The C drive will not be able to be expanded.   AFAIK, not stock windows tools will permit you to re-shape an extended partition after it has been created.

Answer (score 0):

What type of partition did you try to create?  A primary, or logical?  You almost certainly cannot create another primary partition.  I believe the identified space is within an extended partition, which means you can only create logical partitions using that space.

Not the dark green border around the area that identifies the extended partition.

You won't be able to extend the C partition or D partition to use this space using the standard windows tools.

Comment: yes i also think that is extended partition. that was created in ubuntu installation time and that installation was failed. i want use that 69 GB again. but i can not use it now. how can i resolve this ? please help me.

Comment: also i can not extend my c drive

Comment: You wouldn't be able to.  Not with the standard Windows tools.  You are almost to the point where you you might need to seriously look at backing up everything, formatting and then restoring with a better partition layout.  But perhaps someone else has better knowledge of third party tools then I do, and will provide an answer.

Comment: If i will delete all the partitions and recreate them. are you think that will solve the problem ?

Comment: If you are willing to delete things, then you should be able to delete the `D:` drive, and the extended partition.  Then you could extend your `C:` drive, or re-create your `D:` drive using all the space.  Make a good backup first though, just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the green bordered "free space" and delete that partition, this block will then become black "unallocated" like you see on Disk 1 below Disk 0. I believe what you have is already considered a partition.